# perl create view is not working

Tags: perl, sybase, sap-ase

I work with perl and sybase. I try to create view in perl:

```
if(condition)
  create view name_view
   as select col1,col2,col3
  from table1,table2
   where key1=key2
else (condition)
  create view name_view
   as select col1,col2,col2
  from table1,table3
   where key1=key2
```

And when I run it, I always get an error, that view is already exists.
Even I put an  `if - exists` condition.

```
drop view name_view
```

it is always the same error.

Please note: I cannot create a view in separate query, because when I select from view, it works very slow.

Comment: What SAP Sybase product are you using, and how are you checking to see if the view already exists?

Comment: Please remember to use the `sybase-ase` tag, and not just the `sybase` tag.  It will help remove any confusion as to which Sybase DB product you are reffering to.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `prepare` and `execute` call. Please read this excellent post from  [PerlMonks.org](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=518040)